# How to access bitcoin wallet on an android that became unresponsive?

Tags: android, bitcoin-wallet-app, wallet-recovery

My Galaxy S4 mini suddenly stopped working for no apparent reason. It won't turn on via any recommended action or new battery, recovery software from the laptop can't seem to connect as a result. I had bitcoin wallet installed on it with bitcoins inside. How do I access/recover the wallet - or at least coins? Thank you!

Comment: What app did you use? Did you save any backups?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to answer this question without knowing what's wrong with the phone. Your best bet might visiting a repair shop. Tell them you need the data on that phone.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer:  If it is truly bricked, then you need to utilize your backup of that wallet.

### *If you have lost your only copy of your wallet, then my condolences.  The loss of your BTC can be considered a cost of doing business, though - the price of learning from this mistake and instituting better data security practices in the future.*

On having a backup:  Two copies of your wallet introduces more opportunity for unauthorized access, but more data security in terms of protection.

It would be best if your backup wallet is stored in a physical safe.

Also, to reduce your risk, it might be wise to have a master wallet (I use Coinbase) and a second traveling wallet.

Just like you store money in the bank but only carry a small fraction of the total around in your pocket.

Myself, I stick with just Coinbase and their app.  These devices are throw-aways.  But the data must be protected.

Comment: All valid and true, but not really an answer to the question.

Comment: Sorry, @Jannes.  Unfortunately, it is the only answer to the OP question.  Unless you are the FBI, I suppose...

Comment: Well.. If encryption isn't enabled there are data recovery services that can desolder the memory chip and read it directly, for example. Maybe even with encryption, I don't know. Or maybe there are tricks to unbrick said phone (which would probably be an off topic answer here). There's hardly any information in the question and any answer is likely going to be off topic I guess.

Comment: I like the way you think, @Jannes.  If I was hiring I would want you on my team.

Comment: lol. thx. Not sure why I picked this question to comment on after months of slacking. Maybe because I have had a bricked phone on my desk for a year now that was loaded with then $10 of Bitcoin. I guess I'd like to stay hopeful. :)